# TFileSaveDialog - fdoCreatePrompt not showing a prompt?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, save-dialog, tsavedialog

I put a `TFileSaveDialog` on a form in C++ Builder and set the options `fdoOverWritePrompt`, `fdoStrictFileTypes`, `fdoPathMustExist`, and `fdoCreatePrompt`.

When the dialog opens and I select an existing file, it prompts if I want to overwrite like it should.  However, if I type in some random name that doesn't exist and click "*Save*", the dialog just closes - there is no confirmation prompt if it's okay to create one.

Any idea why that is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`OFN_CREATEPROMPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamea), corresponding to

- `TFileSaveDialog`'s [`fdoCreatePrompt`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TFileDialogOption) or
- [`TSaveDialog`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TSaveDialog)'s [`ofCreatePrompt`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenOptions))

is only honored for the **Open** dialog and never for the Save dialog. Try the same thing with a `TFileOpenDialog` and you get that prompt.

Proof for the other dialog types:

```pascal
var
  sd: TSaveDialog;
  od: TOpenDialog;
begin
  sd:= TSaveDialog.Create( self );
  sd.Options:= [ofCreatePrompt];  // Has no effect: no typed-in filename triggers this
  sd.Execute();
  sd.Free;

  od:= TOpenDialog.Create( self );
  od.Options:= [ofCreatePrompt];  // When trying to OPEN a not yet existing file
  od.Execute();
  od.Free;
```

Why? Logic wise when saving a file in the majority of cases you want to create a new file (select a non-existing filename) anyway - why is there a need to confirm that again when you already have the "*Save*" button? Saving a file implies that a file is created. Confirming to overwrite/change an existing file is less common.

If you still want such a behavior you have to do it yourself: use the [`OnCanClose`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TOpenDialog.OnCanClose) event and then check the filename being chosen/entered so far:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.SaveDialog1CanClose(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if not FileExists( SaveDialog1.FileName ) then begin
    // Reject closing the window for every choice but "Yes"
    CanClose:= MessageBox( SaveDialog1.Handle, 'Create it?', 'Does not exist yet', MB_YESNO )= IDYES;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your answer mostly refers to old components, not the newer component the OP is using. `OFN_CREATEPROMPT` is a flag for the old `Get(Open|Save)FileName()` API that `T(Open|Save)Dialog` use. `TFile(Open|Save)Dialog` uses the newer `IFileDialog`/`IFile(Open|Save)Dialog` API instead, which has [`FOS_CREATEPROMPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_fileopendialogoptions). Also, `TFile(Open|Save)Dialog` do not have an `OnCanClose` event like `T(Open|Save)Dialog` do. The `CanClose` parameter is in the `OnFileOkClick` event instead.

Comment: Other than that, your reasoning that a create prompt only applies to an OPEN dialog and not a SAVE dialog is correct.

Comment: So the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @MikeVersteeg yes. Embarcadero's documentation says: "*`fdoCreatePrompt` Prompt for creation if returned item **in save dialog** does not exist. This does not create the item.*" This is wrong. Microsoft's documentation says: "*`FOS_CREATEPROMPT` Prompt for creation if the item returned **in the open dialog** does not exist. Note that this does not actually create the item.*" This is correct.